# Get current latency from Youtube live video

Tags: youtube, live-streaming, latency, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

I am trying to synchronize a youtube live video with a shown presentation on a website. The problem is the latency of the video which differs between 15 and 25 seconds on the clients. When I click "Show stats for nerds" in the video context menu I can see that current latency.

If I knew this latency in the script I could adapt the slide switching accordingly.

So my question is: Is it possible to get the current latency with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get the current latency with JavaScript?

No.

> When I click "Show stats for nerds" in the video context menu I can see that current latency.

That's only the latency YouTube knows about.  There may be other latency as well, on the source end.

I haven't tested it, but you might consider calling `getCurrentTime()`.  It *may* tell you the time offset since the beginning of the encoding, which would be a reliable source for synchronizing other things to the video.

Comment: Thank you...I tried that before, but sadly getCurrentTime is not working for me. It is not delivering reliable values. Currently it even starts with the same value on every page reload, although the live stream has not been stopped.

Comment: @MichaelBammann If that's the case, there's likely nothing you can do.  :-/

Comment: @MichaelBammann You might consider something other than YouTube.